# Programmatic TFS 2010 Event registration + error HTTP code 415: Cannot process the message because the content

Tags: wcf, wcf-hosting

i want to use tfs event registration for reading out the BuildQualityChanged and the WorkItemChanged event. It was working some month before, now i get the following error while getting the event xml:

HTTP code 415: Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..

Im building a console application which will later be an windows service. The code for for hosting the wcf service is the following:

```
private void HostWcfService()
{
    D_("Hosting WCF service");
    var serviceUri = new Uri(GetCorrectServiceAddress());
    _host = new ServiceHost(typeof(BuildQualityChanged), new []{serviceUri});
    AddBehaviors(_host);
    SetBinding(_host, serviceUri);
    _host.Open();
}

private static void AddBehaviors(ServiceHost service)
{
    var smb = service.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceMetadataBehavior>();
    if (smb == null)
    {
        smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
        service.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    }
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;

    var sdb = service.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceDebugBehavior>();
    if (sdb == null)
    {
        sdb = new ServiceDebugBehavior();
        service.Description.Behaviors.Add(sdb);
    }
    sdb.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;
}

private void SetBinding(ServiceHost _host, Uri serviceUri)
{
    // create and configure an MTOM encoder
    var mtom =
        new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(
            MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8);

    // create a CustomBinding using MTOM encoder
    CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();
    binding.Elements.Add(mtom);
    binding.Elements.Add(
        new HttpTransportBindingElement());
    _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TFS.Build.ITeamFoundationEventSubscriber),
        binding, serviceUri);
}
```

All solutions i found until now with this error does configuring the service in web.config, this is no possible solution for me, i have to host programmatically. The second solution i found is to use BasicHttpBinding rather than CustomBinding, but this does not work too for me, the tfs breaks with the same error. I was wondering that the SOAP Version in the WSDL by using BasicHttpBinding is SOAP 1.2 too. SetBinding() for using BasicHttpBinding is

```
var binding1 = new BasicHttpBinding();
            binding1.Name = "binding1";
            binding1.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
            binding1.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
            _host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TFS.Build.ITeamFoundationEventSubscriber), binding1, serviceUri);
```

The only difference in required and given request is the content type, i need application/soap+xml rather than application/xml

Can anyone tell me where my brain is going wrong?

Michael

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching i did not found any solution. A geek of microsoft helps me to get it rid:

TFS2010 only supports wsHttpBinding without security

The content of my SetBinding() method is now the following:

```
var binding1 = new WSHttpBinding();
binding1.Name = "binding1";
binding1.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
binding1.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
_host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(TFS.Build.ITeamFoundationEventSubscriber), binding1, GetCorrectServiceAddress());
```

MAGIC, IT WORKS :)